# Gson type cast error

Tags: java, android, gson

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to anindya.fb.datamodel.Datum`

I have a `HashMap`:

```
static HashMap<String, Datum> favoriteList = new HashMap<>();
```

and I write it to GSON in the following way:

```
String json = gson.toJson(favoriteList);
mEditor.putString(PREF_FAVORITE, json);
mEditor.commit();
```

and get it like this:

```
gson = new Gson();
String json = mPref.getString(PREF_FAVORITE, "");
if (json.equals(""))
   favoriteList = new HashMap<>();
else
   favoriteList = gson.fromJson(json, HashMap.class);
```

To send back a part of this `HashMap` based on a value, I am doing this:

```
ArrayList<Datum> data = new ArrayList<>();
for(String key: favoriteType.keySet()) {
   if(favoriteType.get(key).equals(type)) {  //type is a parameter to this method
       data.add(favoriteList.get(key));
   }
}
return data;
```

However when I try to access this data, I get this error:

```
final Datum curData = data.get(position);
```

gives an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to anindya.fb.datamodel.Datum
```

I came across some posts which mention adding lines in the `proguard` file.

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

but that did not fix the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you're storing a hashmap with type information that's getting dropped when you're reading it.

Change

```
favoriteList = gson.fromJson(json, HashMap.class);
```

to

```
favoriteList = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Datum>>(){}.getType);
```

Comment: Thanks. I beat my head around it for a day! :/

Comment: No worries I've had that bite me a thousand times.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to get the type of `HashMap<String, Datum>`
>   so do this, `Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Datum>>(){}.getType();`
>   then

```
  favoriteList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: your is correct but if it was a class ,but it is not its a collection type thats the reason for the Gson type cast error

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
public Map<String, Datum> toMap(String jsonString) {
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Datum>>(){}.getType();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Map<String, Datum> map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);

    return map;
}
```